# Prevent Hudson from polling/building during certain hours

Tags: hudson

We use SCM polling to initiate builds on our instance of Hudson. This works great for most of our cases, but I need to prevent Hudson from building during certain hours. I've tried to configure the project's Schedule (under Build Triggers) in Hudson by setting it to:

- 0-15 * * *
- 16-23 * * *

Which I thought meant that Hudson would not poll during between 3-4pm. However, if someone checks in during that time, a build is still triggered.

Any clue?

Thanks
Mustafa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

- 0-14 * * *
- 16-23 * * *

Putting the "15" will match anything in the "15th" hour, including between 3-4pm.